# DRCSIM: simulation slows down as robot moves

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is for Gazebo 1.4, drcsim-2.1. Worth testing on Gazebo 1.5, drcsim-2.2

The simulation slows down as the robot is "driven" through a complex environment.

Here is a simple test everyone can do at home:

In terminal window #1

```
source /usr/share/drcsim-2.1/setup.sh
roslaunch atlas_utils vrc_task_1.launch
```

press 'run' and wait more than 10 seconds for the robot to become unpinned.

In terminal window #2

```
source /usr/share/drcsim-2.1/setup.sh
rostopic pub /atlas/set_pose --once 'geometry_msgs/Pose' '{position: {x: 3.0, z: 0.95}, orientation: {z: 0, w: 1}}'
rostopic pub --once /atlas/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear: {x: 1}}'
```

On a dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5-2687W @ 3.10GHz with a Quadra 6000 and
a Tesla K20 GPU:
The simulation starts with the Real Time Factor around 0.92. By the time
the robot reaches the first turn it has declined to 0.36.

On a i7-3770K @ 3.50GHz with a GTX 690 and another i7-3770K with a GTX 650 GPU:
The simulation starts with the Real Time Factor around 1.0. By the time
the robot reaches the first turn it has declined to 0.14.

There is no sign of any rebound of the Real Time Factor if I leave the
simulation running, having stopped the robot motion.

This slowdown does not appear to happen when using our own walking code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1758/drcsim:-simulation-slows-down-as-robot-moves./) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've noticed the exact same behaviour, and it's rather annoying when testing other modules/behaviours. You don't even need to drive it through a complex behaviour, the bug (?) also occurs when using just Atlas + empty world.

I opened a ticket about it a few days ago: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/564/cmd_vel-atlas-gliding-slows-down-gazebo

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-03-16**:
thanks for reporting.  Seems to be a problem with joint destruction not cleaning up completely.  Following up in the ticket.